# Reference / Survey article on automorphisms of groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

can one suggest a survey article on automorphisms of $p$ groups, and automorphisms of abelian groups/ abelian $p$ groups?

Comment: For finite abelian groups, there is the paper "Automorphisms of Finite Abelian Groups" By Hillar and Rhea, AMM 114 (2007), 917--923.

For general p-groups, a lot can be said.  There is a whole book(s) on the subject by Khukhro, and you can find alot of information in the two volumes of Berkovich.

Answer (score 4):

I second the recommendations of Steve D. in his comment: the paper of Hillar and Rhea and Khukhro's book are both excellent.  The two volumes of Berkovich (and Janko for vol. 2) are, as Steve says, full of information but I have found that they do not make for a particularly enjoyable read.

You might also want to look at:
"A survey on automorphism groups of finite p-groups" by Geir Helleloid
and
"Class preserving automorphisms of finite p-groups: A survey" by Manoj Yadav.  I think there are copies of both of these on the Arxiv.

The paper "Some questions about p-groups" by A. Mann has a section discussing some open problems about automorphisms of finite p-groups & is well worth a read.